# How to pass the name of failed task to action argument on Event Log EventID 203?

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

I have a very basic VB script that sends a canned response email when a Scheduled Task fails. I'd love to be able to pass the name of the failed task directly to the script using the Add Arguments option on the Edit Action dialog.

I'm not sure if it is possible, but can't find any references to using the Task Name or any other data associated with a specific EventID. Can this be done in Task Scheduler, or would I have to trawl the Event Log from my script to find the latest failed task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some searching and piecing together of what other people have discovered I've come up with a full solution. The bulk of the answer can be found here:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2011/08/25/trigger-a-powershell-script-from-a-windows-event/

This gives the basics of how to modify the XML of the Task to include additional data. The snippet below shows the specific xpath needed to refer to the name of the task. Just bear in mind that the data returned contains any sub folder name used in Task Scheduler, and if there is a space in this name it will only return the portion of text before the space. I had to recreate all the folders with dashes instead of spaces.

```
<ValueQueries>
 <Value name=”TaskName”>Event/EventData/Data[@Name='TaskName']</Value>
</ValueQueries>
```

This query will give a $(TaskName) argument that can be put into the argument option on the Action tab.

Comment: Thanks, used this with great success. Expanded a bit on your answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/1488344/create-a-scheduled-task-to-trigger-on-a-log-event-with-a-specific-event-id/1488352#1488352